# Can't click on the anchor inside a frame with href value as javascript using selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe

Can't click on the anchor inside a frame with href value as javascript using selenium.

@Note: I could manually click/ call the javascript from IE developer console all looks good. The issue is only through selenium .

Here is the page source like

```
    <html>
<body>
<p>    
<iframe name="iframe1" width="100" height="218" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" "marginheight="0" scrolling="yes">    
<html>
<body>    
<div class="className" id="DivName"onmouseover="startLinkHover(0,70)" onmouseout="stopLinkHover()">
<a name="link0" href="javascript:function()" shape=""> This is link 1 </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working with c# ,IE and selenium

```
Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver" version="2.53.1.1"
Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.0.0"
Selenium.Support" version="3.0.0" 
IE 11 ( As my web application only support IE)
```

Here is what i have tried:
As it the page is consisting of iframe

1) I am switching to iframe and find the anchor using the name  and click

```
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Name("iframe1"));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@name='link0']")).click();
```

2) I have also tried to extract the href property into a string variable and tried to execute the javascript using Javascript executor.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Name("iframe1"));

var js=driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@name='link0']")).GetAttribute("href");

    var jsDriver = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    jsDriver.ExecuteScript(js);
```

Please excuse if any typos as i don't want to post the html source here i have explained my issue with a sample.

Thank you

Comment: Why `<a name="link0" href="javascript:function()" shape=""> This is link 1 </a>`? does `href="javascript:function()"` returns a page from the server or I'm seeing this in a wrong way? where is `href="javascript:function()"` being executed? By __"Can't click on the anchor inside a frame"__ you mean it doesn't do any thing? are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks  Diego ,No It doesn't return a page . Strangely they have used javascript function call from href instead of "onclick" etc. Can't click in the sense it tries to call the function but immediately returns without any exception. No errors on the console. This is a thirdparty application with which we are trying to integrate and i don't have much  help . I wanted to find out what is wrong with the way i am trying to do? and any other better approach for this. And other frustrating thing is F12 is disabled for debugging when running through selenium.

Comment: Do you get any error with the first option you tried? Are you sure you are in the right iframe and you don't have another one before this with similar name?

Comment: No error. Yes there is only one frame with that name . And as you can see from the second option i was able to find the element under that frame and read href property (javascript function)  and trying to exucute that . I have  issues with opening F12 developer tools on IE while debugging . It throws 500 error . But no issues when trying to open F12 if i am trying manually (without selenium debug mode)

Comment: One more thing i noticed is that while debugging even if i want to click directly not through selenium. it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i managed to resolve this issue by reloading the project from source control after pointing the .net framework target version to 4.5 instead of 4.52 (not sure why would this be?).

after investigations , it was proved that issue was not with selenium clicking on the element but the execution of java script after that with page loads.